# Using GNU Screen instead of daemonizing

Tags: daemon, gnu-screen

I just took over a legacy application that launches background processes in GNU screen sessions rather than daemonizing them. I'm trying to figure out why the original programmer wrote it this way. Is there a good reason for launching processes in screen rather than forking them or launching them with `nohup`?

Comment: At least with screen you can directly interact with a process. Once something's daemonized, you're stuck with simple kill signals for the most part, and can only monitor output (if it's writing a log somewhere).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Marc B comment presents a very good point (how unfortunate it is not an answer, it would be a good one!). Anyway, another reason I see is the fact that it is just too easy to use screen for pseudodaemonizing an application.

I, for one, do it a lot. For example, I am developing a Django application for my company, that I will present some time in the future. It is not complete but is useful to me, so I started it in a screen session and leaved it available for use when I need it.